# How to Access USB Connection Logs on Android Without Root Access?

Tags: android, logcat, android-security, usb-debugging, android-log

I am working on a project, and I need to access the USB connection logs for debugging purposes. My main challenge is that the target devices for the application cannot be rooted due to security and policy constraints.

I am aware that Android's security model typically restricts access to system-level logs, including USB connection logs, to prevent unauthorized access. However, I am curious to know if there is any way to access these logs without requiring root access.

Specific questions:

1. Are there any Android APIs or developer tools that provide access to USB connection logs without rooting the device?
2. Is it possible to access these logs through Android's debugging features or any other indirect methods.

Android Version: 12

Any insights, suggestions, or references to official documentation would be greatly appreciated.